# .apk renamed to .txt in AVD

Tags: android, apk

I installed Eclipse ADT but the virtual Android 4.4 keeps renaming apk downloads to txt. I would love to rename them but can't install a file manager to do that because it's an apk too!

I wasn't having this problem with another version of SDK manager/android 4.2.2.

What's the best workaround?

Comment: Why not download them to your dev machine and use `adb install somepackage.apk` ? Also if you use windows, make sure you aren't getting a hidden .txt extension on things there with extension visibility turned off, ie something.apk.txt courtesty of windows.  If you want to download apks directly to the device, you probably need to serve them with the appropriate MIME type as you can read about in a web search if not a search on existing questions here.

Comment: Thanks! they were coming from my Win 7 host, but didn't know about adb command. I'll put an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chris Stratton suggested, use adb install, on Windows it can be found in ...\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools as described here http://www.howtogeek.com/125769/

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same situation with Genymotion.
The root of problem was in config of WWW server. MIME type of .apk file was text/plain.

From Wikipedia:
The MIME type associated with APK files is application/vnd.android.package-archive.

Setting additional MIME type helped me:
apk=application/vnd.android.package-archive

Answer (score 0):

After few experiments i found out that apk is changed to txt due to hosting settings. Unfortunately there is no file manager on android emulator - so you can't rename file.

So your can find webserver that make it possible to download apk file correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings turn on unknown sources. Then use your browser find aptoide install it .use it to install firefox then download apk files this will work